# How to write on google spreadsheet with php curl function

Tags: php

I am working on Google Spreadsheets. I can read values from spreadsheet but cannot write.

My code is:

```
$range = 'Sheet1!A1:A3';
$url_values = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'.$sheet_id.'/values/'.$range.'?key='.$api_key;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_values);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
$output1 = curl_exec($ch);
$output1 = json_decode($output1);
curl_close($ch);
```

I don't know how to send values with this. (same type of code i used to read values, it is working).

Anyone please help me with this.